# Swimlane Number-Card Title Wrap Text

Tags: css, angular, sass, ngx-charts

I am trying to create a simple dashboard to show information at a glance. I am using the swimlane number card chart found here: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/number-card-chart.

Everything is working but I can't get the title of a card to wrap to the next line if it is longer than the card, here is an image of what I am talking about:

[image: titleExample]

I have tried applying style to the parent div and tried with selectors like ".ngx-charts-number-card.title" ".ngx-charts-number-card.title" ".card.title" etc. I can't even modify the style when using the inspector live in the browser. I can't find any documentation to style these elements so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried CSS  white-space style

Comment: I just tried after your comment but it did not change the style at all. 

I tried: 
white-space: normal!important;

I have also tried:
word-wrap: break-word!important

Comment: If possible please provide stackblitz example.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-number-card-chart-8mhrdl

Comment: I forked the example on their website for the stack blitz. It is not my code but the usage is the same. I edited a the first three names to my mimic my problem

Comment: Can I see same issue there?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the first three cards in the stackblitz the names do not wrap to the next line